# In Postman, how can I use several authentication cookies for several users in the same folder?

Tags: api, cookies, request, postman

I'm working on a app feature that is going to be used by different users. I structure the test in a Collection in Postman:

```
- Messaging
    - Thor
        - Get contacts
    - Loki
        - Get contacts
    - Baldr
        - Get contacts
```

In this case, `Messaging`, `Thor`, `Loki` and `Baldr` are collections (folders) while `Get contacts` is the actual request (3 identical requests).

How can one set an authentication cookie for each user in order to get correct response: contacts available for that particular user.

**NOTE:** Tried setting a cookie in 'Manage Cookies' but it's shared among all requests and hence, once I change it for one user, all the users get the same changed cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you cannot achieve that in the postman app. And a feature request for the same has been raised here - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312

However, as a workaround, you can set a new cookie before every request and achieve the results that you want using the collection runner.

```
- Messaging
    - Thor
        - Authentication Request (Sets new cookie)
        - Get contacts (Thor)
    - Loki
        - Authentication Request (Sets new cookie)
        - Get contacts (Loki)
    - Baldr
        - Authentication Request (Sets new cookie)
        - Get contacts (Baldr)
```

Now, just run this collection using the collection runner and write your tests or check the responses that were needed.

Refer the [Collection Runner Documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/starting_a_collection_run)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sivcan. And of course, thanks for the suggested workaround: since the feature is still not supported in Postman, will implement your solution for collection runner. Thank you.